# Making app unusable in client device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, ios-provisioning

I have created a build for my client with my developer account and sent him the build. Now I want to make the build unusable ie the build shouldnt work now when he opens the app.
Should I delete the certificates and provisioning profile ? Would that work.
Also, does internet connection on device have a role in that ?

Comment: There is nothing you can do now. The client can use your app until the developer certificate expires on its own sometime in the next 12 months. You should have built an expiration into the app before sending it.

Comment: if I revoke the certificate now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rmaddy say you can't do anything at that moment. Sorry!! it's your bad luck but don't worry forget about what happens but from now don't forget to set expiration code into your app before deliver it to your client. And also don't forget to remove expiration code when you finally submit it.

[Learn how to set expiration code](http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/2927896024/how-i-expire-my-ios-beta-app)